# Android media playback - stop audio output completely?

Tags: android, audio

I have an app that plays video files with no audio.  I'm using the `mediaplayer` function.  I want to have the videos play, but not output anything to audio, as there is no audio tracks.  However, Android ducks all other audio output (music, for example) when my app is running.  Is there a way to use `mediaplayer` and completely remove my app from audio streams?

I've reviewed Google's [Managing Audio Focus](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) article, and I can't devise a way to do so.  I just want to use mediaplayer for the video, and completely forget about audio.

Is there a different function I have to call in `mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType`?

Answer (score 0):

you can mute all the audio streams using the below code snippet

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)NextVideoPlayer.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```